# What functionality do 'marks' offer in the El Capitan Terminal?

Tags: terminal, macos

Since upgrading to OS X El Capitan, I've noticed a change in the Terminal: Executed lines show an opening bracket on the left, and a closing bracket on the right, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Terminal]

Similar questions have been asked here:

- https://superuser.com/questions/974714/previous-commands-wrapped-with-square-brackets-in-os-x-terminal
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888295/why-is-a-being-added-to-my-prompt-after-upgrading-to-os-x-10-11
- [Changes to Terminal in El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208384/changes-to-terminal-in-el-capitan)
- [Why is there a left bracket before my bash prompt?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/199496/why-is-there-a-left-bracket-before-my-bash-prompt)
- [New Terminal behavior after upgrading to OS X 10.11](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208975/new-terminal-behavior-after-upgrading-to-os-x-10-11)

Some of the questions are referring to these brackets as *marks*, and the Terminal's *Edit* menu has a couple of entries related to *marks*, for example:

- *Edit > Marks > Mark as Prompt and Send Return*
- *Edit > Clear to Previous Mark*
- *Edit > Navigate > Jump to Previous Mark*

[image: Edit Menu]

Is there a summary of what these marks can be used for? I have not seen any reference to this new feature in any of the El Capitan feature overviews.

Comment: If only we had found a better way to pay Siracusa enough to scrutinize the OS for months on end....

Answer (score 165, accepted):

## Marks in the Terminal

The new Terminal *marks* (available starting with OS X 10.11 - El Capitan) are similar to *Bookmarks*, which are also available in the Terminal, allowing you to mark window positions and then giving you the option of going back at a later point.

Marks (or Bookmarks) don't refer to your command history, but to the scroll buffer used in the Terminal window/tab.

## Marking a Line

By default, every time you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the Terminal window, the line is *marked*, which is displayed using an opening bracket at the beginning of the line and a closing one at the very end. This default behavior can be turned off using the *Edit > Marks > Automatically Mark Prompt Lines* menu entry. When this is disabled, you can still manually execute and mark a command using <kbd>Cmd+Enter</kbd> (or with the *Edit > Marks > Mark as Prompt and Send Return* menu entry).

If you have automatic marking enabled and want to run a command without marking it as a *prompt*, you can do this using <kbd>Cmd+Shift+Enter</kbd> (or with the *Edit > Marks > Send Return Without Marking* menu entry).

## Disabling Marks

Automatic marking of lines can be disabled using the *Edit > Marks > Automatically Mark Prompt Lines* menu entry.

From the command line, the same can be achieved using

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal AutoMarkPromptLines -bool NO
```

## Hiding Marks

If you want to use the *mark* functionality, but don't want to see the brackets at the beginning and end of the line, you hide them using the *View > Hide Marks* menu entry. This will keep the below functionality intact, but will no longer show the brackets.

## Jumping between Marks

Once a line has been marked, you can quickly jump to the previous mark using <kbd>Cmd+Up</kbd> or to the next one using <kbd>Cmd+Down</kbd>. Similar options are provided for Bookmarks, and for selecting to the next/previous mark:

[image: Edit Menu]

## Manually Marking a Line

In addition to the automatic marking, you can also manually add marks by selecting a line in the terminal output using the mouse, and then selecting the *Edit > Marks > Mark as Prompt* menu entry (or <kbd>Cmd+U</kbd>).

## Use Cases

The *Marks* functionality is useful if some of your executed commands produce lots of output, and you quickly want to scroll to the position where you entered the command. Pressing <kbd>Cmd+Up</kbd> will take you there. Pressing it repeatedly will take you further up, while pressing <kbd>Cmd+Down</kbd> will take you back down again. The target location is conveniently highlighted as you jump/scroll around.

[image: Marks Usage]

## Selecting Content

The same *marks* functionality can be used for selecting Terminal output. Pressing <kbd>Cmd+Shift+Up</kbd> will select the content up to the previous mark, while <kbd>Cmd+Shift+Down</kbd> will select down to the next mark. This is useful when wanting to copy log output or other content from the Terminal.

This functionality is also available from the *Edit > Navigate* menu while pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key:

[image: Navigate Menu]

## Summary

Having used this for a couple of days now, I find it incredibly useful. Scrolling up through hundreds of lines of output to find the beginning of the command's output has suddenly become a lot easier.

I wonder why this new feature isn't mentioned more prominently - I haven't seen it in any of the El Capitan walkthroughs. The Terminal help currently does not provide any details on this feature either.

Comment: Great answer. Just to add a little bit, Bookmarks can be named too, so think of Bookmarks as Chapters in a book and marks as Paragraphs. You could create a new Bookmark when starting a new task in the same Terminal, handy in recalling exactly where you started and what you did.

Comment: This is actually really useful. Thanks for this great explanation! I was wondering why I observed the same thing months back, but I ignored it, until I realized it had nothing to do with my modified PS1. Great!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a form of 'quick/light bookmarking'. I guess disabling 'Automatically mark prompt lines' makes its function more evident. After doing that, Cmd-Enter explicitly saves the mark, and Cmd-Up/Down jumps between them.

As you can convert marks to bookmarks and vice versa, I'd see them as lightweight or second-level bookmarks.

Comment: That doesn't seem entirely accurate. When I use _Cmd+Up_, it doesn't cycle through my history, but scrolls the whole Terminal window to the previously _marked_ command.

Comment: I do not have El Capitan installed (yet) and my answer is a bit off-topic.

If this is a history search feature like mentions by @fonso, it looks like Apple reengineered the old <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> feature of bash, where you could do a reverse interactive history search. And Apple seems having visualized it.

Comment: No, it's not. As I have said in my comment, it does not have any overlap with the CTRL+R history search. It looks like the _marks_ feature works as a kind of automatic bookmark, letting you scroll up through the terminal window's buffer quickly.

Comment: Sorry, you're all completely right, it's marking the scroll point, not history! I'll edit the answer.