# Can a Terminal Mark be added via a shell command?

Tags: terminal, command-line

MacOS' Terminal's marks are an incredible feature. They allow you to add a "marker" to a line, which can be jumped between. Documentation about these commands is available in [Apple's own documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/use-marks-and-bookmarks-trml135fbc26/), as well as previous questions here;

- [Why is there a left bracket before my bash prompt?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/199496/1346)
- [New Terminal behavior after upgrading to OS X 10.11](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/208975/1346)
- [What functionality do 'marks' offer in the El Capitan Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/209635/1346)

I often have a need to run a command repeatedly, which I tend to do via a shell script that puts a command in a while loop with a sleep timer, or an execution counter with a limit. Paging through executions is difficult unless I remember to also add some kind of marker like `echo "---------"` in the command chain.

Is it possible to add marks via shell scripting? My searches so far only show the menu option and keyboard shortcut.

Comment: The only solutions I've found using AppleScript (more specifically, `osascript`) in the terminal require telling Terminal to activate which brings it to the foreground, bad for (1) multiple tabs and (2) leaving in the background for a non-specific amount of time.